# Anaconda does not allow the creation of a new environment

Tags: python, anaconda

I am just starting out with Anaconda, and trying to create a new environment. However, when I try to do this using the navigator, it giver the following error:

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda 
forge/win-64/repodata.json><br>Elapsed: None<br><br>An HTTP error occurred 
when trying to retrieve this URL.<br>HTTP errors are often intermittent, 
and a simple retry will get you on your way.<br>ConnectionError

(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org', port=443):
 Max retries exceeded with url: /t/<TOKEN>/conda-forge/win-64/repodata.json
(Caused by NewConnectionError    
('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at  
0x0000000004C39080>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] 
getaddrinfo failed',))",),)<br>
```

I have been reading a lot online and I think it has something to do with the .condarc file. However, I can't figure out how to solve this issue. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: How many open socket do you have? `netstat -np | wc -l`

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by this. Where do I enter this?

Comment: Have you installed Anaconda for All users, is it under Windows?